# I am facing issue on cloining git repo "Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected"

Tags: git, github, repository, egit, cloning

[Premature end of chunk coded message body: closing chunk expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62Tg5.png)

Comment: What happens if you try again?

Comment: @evolutionxbox it shows same, I tried uninstalling EGit and installed again but same error.